# Ubuntu 23.04 Upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 failed

Tags: updates, 23.04

I successful installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my HP Laptop. Then I Upgrades to 23.04 by changing the setting. The Update started but near the end Ubuntu Said the Program stopped working, I think IT stopped at installing something Like Gnome. Then I pressed sometimes "wait" but it won't worked. The program called "lunar" which crashed. Is there anything I should do. Everything apart from the crash all works fine and Ubuntu is a very great.

Thank you for help

Comment: "*Then I Upgrades to 23.04 by changing the setting*" this suggests that you used an unsupported method. We do not provide support for unsupported methods. Backup your data (if any), make a fresh 23.04 install USB, and do a clean install of Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: @user535733 No, I mean I opened the software updater settings and changed it to "Every release" from originaly "LTS" releases, this was described on the official Ubuntu website

Comment: That should offer you a release-upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10, not directly to 23.04. "Something like" and "The program called "lunar" which crashed" are too vague for us to understand what is happening. Sorry.

Comment: I just fixed the issue by making a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and then upgrading to 23.04. Even with a Virtual Machine of Ubuntu the updater offers me Ubuntu 23.04 upgrade directly when changing the setting from every LTS release to every release in the settings as it was described on the Ubuntu webpage.